# Is there a general method for solving a cubic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm doing a course in linear algebra at the moment, and whenever I need to find the eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix, I'm faced with the issue that I don't know a general method for solving a cubic equation, or I don't remember enough from high school algebra to be able to solve any given cubic equation.

For instance, if I have the characteristic equation

$$-\lambda^3+8\lambda^2-19\lambda+12=0$$

then I can't factor it easily because 19 is a prime number, but a computer was able to somehow find it's solutions for me.

Is there a general, algorithmic method for solving *any* given cubic equation without factorization? If not, how would you solve an equation like the above?

And is there a similar kind of general method for solving quartic or higher degree polynomials?

Comment: for higher polynomials of degree more than $4$ answer is NO...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: If you search the site for Cardano or cubic this is answered many times.

Comment: 19 being prime is not important.  You should worry more about the constant term.  For example, the quadratic equation $X^2-pX+7(p-7)$ has solutions $7, p-7$, for any $p$, prime or not.

Comment: But $X^2 - aX + p$ usually doesn't have solutions, by the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use Rational roots theorem.

The R.R. Theorem says the rational roots of $-\lambda^3 + 8\lambda^2 -19\lambda + 12$ have to be of the form 
$$
\pm \frac{a}{1}
$$
where $a$ is a factor of $12$

Answer (score 2):

For the cubic equations you can use (even if is really complicated) the [Cardano Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

There are results in Agebra that show there are no such closed formulas for higher degree equations. This depends on the non-solvability property of permutations groups $S_n$ for $n>4$